# How to set response Content-Length to infinite

Tags: html, request, web2py, content-length

I try to create an application in `web2py` framework. By default `web2py` server has `Transfer-Encoding: Chunked` header for response, but in that case when target remote web application sends GET request to my app it could get only first string of text from requested page (from file's content that displayed on page). If to use `Content-Length` instead, for example, with value of 1000 it will get 1000 bytes of data from page... But if I expect to response with huge range of data, how to set `Content-Length` parameter to infinity or by file (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485042/how-to-set-content-length-by-send-file) but with `web2py` syntax instead of `php` )?

Comment: Why do you now know the size of your response in the first place? Not sure I understand

Comment: files could be various with different sizes, so I don't know what size of response will actually be, so I need to response with all data, that file contain, no matter what size is

Comment: Then I suppose the solution is not to send a `content-length` header in the first place. (Edit: this Wikipedia article seems to suggest the same: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)

Comment: Original question answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31882961/440323). In short, use `response.stream` rather than `Expose` to serve the files, in which case, the Content-Length header will be set.

Answer (score 0):

If you are serving web2py via the built-in development server and serving files via the [`Expose`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/14/other-recipes#Publishing-a-folder) functionality, then the files will be served via chunked transfer encoding.

However, if you instead use [`response.stream`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#response) to serve files, the Content-Length header will be set automatically.